# Power supply on the Google TV Revue

Tags: power-consumption, google-tv

Does anyone know how much power the Logitech Revue consumes?  I can't find it anywhere...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on FCC photos of the power brick ([source](http://www.gtvhub.com/2010/07/05/logitech-revue-gets-a-little-fcc-treatment-includes-photo-gallery/)), it will take 3A at 12V for 36W.

Answer (score 0):

The Logitech Revue specs page is below, but I can't find the power requirements either...Perhaps ask the via email or phone?  Not sure if they will tell you before the product has been released...

> http://www.logitech.com/en-us/smartTV/revue#section=specs

Contact Logitech URL: http://www.logitech.com/en-us/support-downloads/support-contactus?section=phone